# Why searching throws call to undefined error method stmt::fetch_row()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I try to query a database using SELECT statement, it works fine, but when I try to filter rows returned by appending LIKE clause to the original query, it throws a fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_row()

```
if (isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $searchString = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
    $queryStringAppend = " WHERE name LIKE ? OR state LIKE ?";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName " . $queryStringAppend);
    //|| die("Ooops! Error occured: <br/>" . $mysqli->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $searchString, $searchString);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($mysqli->error)     // CHECK IF ERROR HANDLER IS WORKING
        die("Query failed: <br />" . $mysqli->error);
}
 else
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName ");
    if ($mysqli->error)
        die("Query failed: <br />" . $mysqli->error);
}

$totalRowCount = $stmt->fetch_row()[0];  // This is the line where the error is thrown
```

When the $_POST["search"] is not set, the query works fine and all the results show. But, if I try to filter, the error is thrown  :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because fetch_row is a method of `mysqli_result`, not `mysqli_stmt`
You need to store your result first

```
    $results = $stmt->get_result()
    $results->fetch_row()[0];
```

In the second `if`, `mysqli->query("")` directly return a `mysqli_result` object, that is why it executes without error;